# Converting/handling returned IList object

Tags: c#, winforms, list, object

I'm having issues extracting values from a returned IList and populating a combobox in windows.forms. All items in the combobox are listed as `System.object`.

I have done some testing;

```
var retList = Services.Get<IWarehouseInfo>().ExecuteSPArray("sp_executesql", dict); <-- method that returns some values.
//Tries to extract value from retlist/which is a IList<object[]> collection.

        var strList = (from o in retList select o.ToString()).ToList();
        var strList2 = retList.OfType<string>().ToList();
        var strList3 = retList.Cast<string>();
        var strList4 = retList.Where(x => x != null).Select(x => x.ToString()).ToList(); //All these seem to result in system object. 

        var bub = strList.ElementAt(2).ToString();

        var bob = strList4.ElementAt(2).ToString();
        var kupa = strList.ToArray();
        var kupo = kupa[2].ToString();
```

All these fail to extract anything useful.

Comment: Your positive your Dependency Injection is correctly retrieving and calling your Stored Procedure?  If you do:  `var content = collection.Where(projection => projection != null);`. Does it actually show anything being returned?  Also, you could simply do: `var content = collection.Select(projection => projection).ToList())` though I'm not sure how useful that truly is.

Comment: What useful you want to extract? What is your expectations? What actually you are getting? Any error? What error? What is the purpose of this code?

Comment: Insufficient data to answer

Comment: The comment says that it returns a list of arrays.  None of the statements actually look at the array elements.  So sure, nothing interesting to look at, Array does not override ToString().

Comment: I thank you all for any beeps given. My mistake was that I thought that the returned values were in a list of objects. But the result was an IEnumerable<object[]>, so I did not check the correct vector.

I added an method extracting the values and returning it in desired format, in this case string.

Answer (score 1):

> I thank you all for any beeps given. My mistake was that I thought
>   that the returned values were in a list of objects. But the result was
>   an IEnumerable, so I did not check the correct vector.

I added an method extracting the values and returning it in desired format, in this case string.

```
 private static List<string> ToListString(IEnumerable<object[]> inparam)
    {
        var custNums = new List<string>();

        foreach (var row in inparam)
        {
            if (row[0] != null && row[0] != DBNull.Value)
                custNums.Add(row[0].ToString());
        }

        return custNums;
    }
```